Chromatic Polynomial of a graph using fusion and adding edges to non adjacent vertices
I am working on finding the chromatic polynomial of a specific graph.
I understand that the chromatic polynomial can be found using edge addition and vertex fusion techniques, but I'm not sure how to apply these methods effectively.
Could someone help me find the chromatic polynomial of this graph?
Graph
Any guidance on the process or detailed steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Which graph${}$?

Link has been provided!

Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Sorry i am new to this platform.
